# How to retrieve results of meta_values by meta_value and meta_key?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to SELECT all the meta values from my WP database where meta_value = 'x' and meta_key = 'y'. But my query returns nothing:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `tst_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'thevoters' AND meta_value = 'mint'
```

What am I doing wrong here?!

**Update**

The query should return the meta_value column with some ids based on meta_key called 'the_voters' but also where meta_value equals 'mint'.

I've also tried this query:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM `tst_postmeta` WHERE meta_key = 'thevoters' AND meta_key = 'sticker_chosen' AND meta_value = 'mint'
```

Comment: I am not specialist in WP, but few questions - Do you realy have something, that can be selected by your "filter" And according to Your query You can get just one result - `mint`

Comment: you don't have rows matching this criteria

Comment: @demo, I know it returns nothing because it doesn't match. I've updated my question with what I expect my query to do, in case I wasn't clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: Your SQL is correct, your logic is incorrect. Remove your conditions and try again.

Comment: @vkp, yes, that's true, updated my question with what I expect my query to do but my query above is where I got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little information you offered and your query my guess is that no data exists for your query.

Have you tried seeing what shows up when you run

```
SELECT * 
FROM tst_postmeta
```

This should show you everything in your table and you can filter by meta key and meta value in your result to see if anything exists for those values.

You can also try breaking down your query into two queries to see if either provides a result, if nothing shows up for either query then there will be no values when you combine them.

```
SELECT meta_value 
FROM tst_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = 'thevoters' 

SELECT meta_value 
FROM tst_postmeta 
WHERE meta_value = 'mint'
```

Comment: When something appears you do not expect, remove all you can (within your power) and re-approach it with a cleaner simpler mindset.

Comment: @Bavard, I've updated my question with a little more information, just in case I wasn't clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous His answer unfortunately still is correct. This is how you should approach this. Break it down.

Comment: @Anonymous Try the second option I just added as well. Let me know if either query gives you any results

Comment: @Bavard, both of them are giving me column with results. That is not my problem. I want to combine the two select queries as you said above, into one. and get only the meta_values of meta_key='thevoters'. where meta_value = 'mint'.

Comment: Well now you know that results exist for each qualifier you are using so my guess is that when you combine them no rows are being found because no entries in your database have both a value of meta_key='thevoters' and meta_value= 'mint'

Comment: Well, I knew that also, meta_key column contains both: "thevoters" and "sticker_chosen" and meta_value column contains both: the id I want to get and the 'mint'.

Comment: Yes but I am not sure you are following the logic people are trying to tell you to use to solve your issue. You need to use process of elimination. There is probably no record which shares both of the values you are filtering for hence no results...

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is correct, but you have no data in your result set.